# Перестает работать Button в DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Дано DataTemplate, в котором определена кнопка:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localVM:SwitchISViewModel}">
    <Grid Background="..."}"
          >               
        <Button
                Margin="5"
                Content="{Binding Name}"
                Command="{Binding ExecuteComand}"                
                />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Далее в Grid использую этот Template

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentControl
                Margin="4"
                Content="{Binding SwitchIS[0]}"                
                >
            </ContentControl>
            <ContentControl
                Margin="4"
                Content="{Binding SwitchIS[1]}"                
                >
            </ContentControl>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

где SwitchIS это массив SwitchISViewModel, определенный во MainViewModel.
Дело в том, что все привязывается. Первые разы при кликанье на Button я попадаю в ExecuteComand. Потом не кликается. В чем может быть дело.

ps Пытался сделать через ContentPresenter:
Определил

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateVM"> ....
```

Вместо ContentControl вставил ContentPresenter

```
<ContentPresenter
    Content="{Binding SwitchIS[0]}"
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateVM}"
/>
```

Результат тот же.

Comment: есть возможность написать MCVE?

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: исправил, так лучше?

Comment: Без SwitchISViewModel вопрос не полный

Comment: Да, согласен. Без SwitchISViewModel  не полно.
Но я разобрался. 
Моя MainViewModel  содержала в себе SwitchISViewModel.
До этого все RelayCommand были определенны во MainViewModel . Затем я решил упростить из-за повторяющихся блоков и создал SwitchISViewModel, куда были перенесены RelayCommand. Результатом стал частичный отказ работы. Проблема решилась выставлением флага keepTargetAlive = true в RelayCommand.
Может кто дать объяснение сильных и слабых ссылок? или ткнуть где читать?

Comment: @КонстантинМефодьев: А что за реализация `RelayCommand` у вас?

Comment: Использую MVVMLight